# Powershell to Monitor Website Availablity

Tags: powershell

I have a PS script which monitors all websites listed in text file. As of now i i am running it as a job so whenever any of website goes down it throws an alert on registered mail ID with the HTML file as an attachment consisting of all website status. What i want now that it only pick the those websites which goes down and throes me an alert. Can someone help me here please.

Script:-

```
$URLListFile = "C:\Users\Desktop\URL.txt"  
$URLList = Get-Content $URLListFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
  $Result = @() 


  Foreach($Uri in $URLList) { 
  $time = try{ 
  $request = $null 
   ## Request the URI, and measure how long the response took. 
  $result1 = Measure-Command { $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri } 
  $result1.TotalMilliseconds 
  }  
  catch 
  { 
   <# If the request generated an exception (i.e.: 500 server 
   error or 404 not found), we can pull the status code from the 
   Exception.Response property #> 
   $request = $_.Exception.Response 
   $time = -1 
  }   
  $result += [PSCustomObject] @{ 
  Time = Get-Date; 
  Uri = $uri; 
  StatusCode = [int] $request.StatusCode; 
  StatusDescription = $request.StatusDescription; 
    TimeTaken =  $time;  
  } 

} 
    #Prepare email body in HTML format 
if($result -ne $null) 
{ 
    $Outputreport = "<HTML><TITLE>Website Availability Report</TITLE><BODY background-color:peachpuff><font color =""#99000"" face=""Microsoft Tai le""><H2> Website Availability Report </H2></font><Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><TR bgcolor=gray align=center><TD><B>URL</B></TD><TD><B>StatusCode</B></TD><TD><B>StatusDescription</B></TD><TD><B>TimeTaken</B></TD</TR>" 
    Foreach($Entry in $Result) 
    { 
        if($Entry.StatusCode -ne "200") 
        { 
            $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=red>" 
             send-mailmessage -to "abc@gmail.com" -from "abc@gmail.com" -subject "Test mail" -SmtpServer XXX@###.com -Attachments "C:\Users\Desktop\Test.htm"

        } 
        else 
        { 
            $Outputreport += "<TR>" 
        } 
        $Outputreport += "<TD>$($Entry.uri)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusCode)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusDescription)<TD align=center>$($Entry.timetaken)</TD></TR>" 
    } 
    $Outputreport | out-file C:\Users\Desktop\Test.htm 

    $Outputreport += "</Table></BODY></HTML>" 
}
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. There are tools (some free, some paid) which will monitor your website better and more reliably than a custom script.

Comment: Agreed on your point . My question is it possible to modify above script

Comment: Yes, it's possible to modify that script. What have you done to that end? I don't see any attempt in the code to build a list of the sites that fail the check.

Comment: @Abhishek Does your $result variable contain the 'Where' method?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this. First I assume you are trying to capture each item from $results where the status code is anything other than a success code. If this assumption is correct then you already have most of the solution in your code. The following line:

```
if($Entry.StatusCode -ne "200") 
{ 
    $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=red>" 
     send-mailmessage -to "abc@gmail.com" -from "abc@gmail.com" -subject "Test mail" -SmtpServer XXX@###.com -Attachments "C:\Users\Desktop\Test.htm"

}
```

is identifying those records, so you can simply grab them here in the loop. Like this:

```
if($Entry.StatusCode -ne "200") 
{ 
    $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=red>" 
     send-mailmessage -to "abc@gmail.com" -from "abc@gmail.com" -subject "Test mail" -SmtpServer XXX@###.com -Attachments "C:\Users\Desktop\Test.htm"
 $failedCodeUri += $Entry.uri
}
```

In the above snippet the variable $failedCodeUri must be declared with the scope necessary to be accessible inside and outside of the foreach loop. This can be done as simply as declaring the variable on a line immediately preceding the beginning of the foreach loop. It also must be a type that can utilize the += operator. This can be done with a simple array like this.

```
$failedCodeUri = @()
```

Of course if you need to capture more than just the uri you will need a more sophisticated data type than a simple array of strings.

The other possible solution depends on the 'where' method being available on your $results object. If it is available you can simply do this:

```
$failedCodeUri = $results.where({$_.StatusCode -ne "200"})
```

This last technique would not be used inside the loop. Either before or after your foreach loop you can use this line of code to return all of the desired results.

A few things to note about this technique:
Within the 'where' code block the condition is being checked for each item in the result set. You reference the current item with $_ using the dot operator to access a property or method that exists for that item.

In the above example the entire item, with all of its properties will be returned. If you only want the uri you can do something like this:

```
$failedCodeUri = $results.where({$_.StatusCode -ne "200"}).uri
```